# Horizontally centering the active image of a bxSlider carousel with a seamless loop?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bxslider

I want to make a really simple seamlessly-looping carousel and have tried using bxSlider, but am encountering an issue where my images are off-center.

I have 3 x 1000px wide images and all I want to do is ensure the active image is in the middle of the browser, with the other two images infinitely looping on the left/right sides, like so:

[image]

I've tried using a negative-margins trick (`left: 50%` and `margin-left: -500px`) but it didn't work and bxSlider went kind of crazy.

My code is very simple and I have a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/j3hgA/

```
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/pOh3bXm.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/VrvQUzu.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/pJr77Ee.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a "simple" CSS problem.

I'd set my carousel's `.bx-wrapper` to 5000px wide, to accommodate the main 3 × 1000px wide slides, plus the 2 × 1000px wide "overflow" slides which bxSlider generates to the left and right of the carousel to achieve the "seamless" effect.

I therefore should have had `margin-left: -2500px; left: 50%;` on my carousel's main wrapper div. That is, a margin-left that is half of the *total width* of the whole carousel, not just of one image.

The final CSS, therefore, was something like:

```
#slideshow-wrapper {
    width: 1000px;        /* Width of single slide */
    margin-left: -2500px; /* Half of total carousel width including overflow images */
    left: 50%;
}

#slideshow-wrapper .bx-wrapper {
    width: 5000px !important; /* Total width including overflow images */
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Finally, I was seeing a "white flash" or "pop-in" to the right of the slider every time it looped. This was because I hadn't set bxSlider's `displaySlideQty` option, which determines how many slides should be visible on the screen at any time.

The default `displaySlideQty` is 1, but in my case, I actually had parts of 3 images displayed in the viewport, so bxSlider wasn't pre-rendering the left/right "overflow" or "seamless" images at the right time. Changing `displaySlideQty` to 3 worked, and the slideshow loops infinitely.

```
$("#slider").bxSlider({
    moveSlides: 1,
    displaySlideQty: 2,
    responsive: false,
    infiniteLoop: true
});
```

Answer (score 7):

### **This is what you need..**

***DEMO :-***
http://jsfiddle.net/dush88gs/rj9r74a0/41/

Complete code is here
 **HTML**

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.bxslider.css"/>  
</head>

<body>
    <div class="bxslider">
      <div class="slide"><img src="images/1.jpg" width="1000" /></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="images/2.jpg" width="1000" /></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="images/3.jpg" width="1000" /></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="images/4.jpg" width="1000" /></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="images/5.jpg" width="1000" /></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="images/6.jpg" width="1000" /></div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 900,
        minSlides: 2,
        maxSlides: 3,
        moveSlides: 1,
        pager: false,
        auto: true
      });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
div.bxslider {
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
}
```

Comment: I cant figure out how to only have 10% margin on the left and right and still get the same effect. The left offset slide is correct, but the right offset slide shows 40%ish rather than 10%. So basically the active slide isn't wide enough. 

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For having the slider to the center one have to contain the carousel into a container, so insert slider into a container...

**HTML:-**

```
<div class="slide-contain">
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/pOh3bXm.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/VrvQUzu.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/pJr77Ee.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:-**

```
.slide-contain { margin: 0 auto; width:1000px; }
```

And for infinite loop, you have to insert the parameter to make the slider work...

**JS:-**

```
$("#slider").bxSlider({
    moveSlides: 1,
    displaySlideQty: 2,
    responsive: false,
    infiniteLoop: true
});
```

Like the answer below...

**DEMO:-** http://jsfiddle.net/j3hgA/2/show/

Thanks, hope that works for you...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need..

http://jsfiddle.net/j3hgA/1/

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    width: 3000px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -1500px;
}

li {
    float: left;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it seems bxSlider overrides my ul width. The slides appear way off-center, and it doesn't loop seamlessly - there's loads of nasty white space.

Comment: So I'm working with a jsfiddle which isn't the thing u need. Please share your REAL code so thing can be worked out, I can't fix anything if you dont show the real code.

Comment: The real code is identical except for it's tied up in a big messy web page from a CMS. I've made an almost-working version, [here](http://paste2.org/PYAeeskI) which is centered, but does exhibit the white-space problem I was talking about. You'll notice as you scroll through the images, there's a big white gap instead of a seamless infinite loop. Thanks for your help. *Edit:* the above linked code works in Firefox but apparently not Chrome. Damn it.

Comment: The issue was not really with the code but because I was actually displaying 3 slides in my viewport at once, not just 1 slide. I had to set `displaySlideQty` to 3 and edit the CSS a bit: see my answer for more.